# Rendering Object with Texture in OpenGL

Tags: c++, opengl

I'm trying to put a texture in my model, but it doesn't work, the model is drawn without the texture.

This function loads the texture, at first it should be working perfectly fine, because I already used it in another program. I'm calling this function at the main function putting the result in the global variable called modelTexture.

```
GLuint initTexture(char* filename) {
   BITMAPINFO *info;
   GLubyte *ptr, *bits, *rgba, *rgbaptr;
   GLuint texture, temp;
   GLenum type;
   bits = LoadDIBitmap(filename, &info);
   if (bits == (GLubyte *)0) {
   return NULL;
   }
   if (info->bmiHeader.biHeight == 1)
       type = GL_TEXTURE_1D;
   else
   type = GL_TEXTURE_2D;
   glGenTextures(1, &texture);
   glBindTexture(type, texture);
   glTexParameteri(type, GL_TEXTURE_MAG_FILTER, GL_LINEAR);
   glTexParameteri(type, GL_TEXTURE_MIN_FILTER, GL_LINEAR_MIPMAP_LINEAR);
   glTexParameteri(type, GL_TEXTURE_WRAP_S, GL_REPEAT);
   glTexParameteri(type, GL_TEXTURE_WRAP_T, GL_REPEAT);
   rgba = (GLubyte *)malloc(info->bmiHeader.biWidth * info->bmiHeader.biHeight * 4);
   int i = info->bmiHeader.biWidth * info->bmiHeader.biHeight;
   for(rgbaptr = rgba, ptr = bits;  i > 0; i--, rgbaptr += 4, ptr += 3){
       rgbaptr[0] = ptr[2];
       rgbaptr[1] = ptr[1];
       rgbaptr[2] = ptr[0];
       rgbaptr[3] = (ptr[0] + ptr[1] + ptr[2])/3;
   }
   gluBuild2DMipmaps(GL_TEXTURE_2D, 4, info->bmiHeader.biWidth, info->bmiHeader.biHeight, GL_RGBA, GL_UNSIGNED_BYTE, rgba);
   return texture;
}
```

So, here is the display callback, where I draw the model.

```
void renderGL(void){
    glClear(GL_COLOR_BUFFER_BIT | GL_DEPTH_BUFFER_BIT);
    glEnable(GL_DEPTH_TEST);
    glFrontFace(GL_CW);
    glCullFace (GL_BACK);
    glEnable(GL_CULL_FACE);
    glMatrixMode(GL_PROJECTION);
    glLoadIdentity();
    gluPerspective(angle, aspRatio, zNear, zFar);
    glMatrixMode(GL_MODELVIEW);
updateCamera();
    glPolygonMode(GL_FRONT_AND_BACK, GL_FILL);
glEnable(GL_TEXTURE_2D);
    glBindTexture(GL_TEXTURE_2D, modelTexture);
    glTexEnvi(GL_TEXTURE_ENV, GL_TEXTURE_ENV_MODE, GL_REPLACE);
    int i;
    for (i = 0; i < object.NumTris; i++){
        glBegin(GL_TRIANGLES);
            glNormal3f(object.Tris[i].normal[0].x, object.Tris[i].normal[0].y, object.Tris[i].normal[0].z);
            glTexCoord2f(0.0f, 0.0f);
            glVertex3f(object.Tris[i].v0.x, object.Tris[i].v0.y, object.Tris[i].v0.z);
            glNormal3f(object.Tris[i].normal[1].x, object.Tris[i].normal[1].y, object.Tris[i].normal[1].z);
            glTexCoord2f(0.5f, 1.0f);
            glVertex3f(object.Tris[i].v1.x, object.Tris[i].v1.y, object.Tris[i].v1.z);
            glNormal3f(object.Tris[i].normal[2].x, object.Tris[i].normal[2].y, object.Tris[i].normal[2].z);
            glTexCoord2f(1.0f, 0.0f);
            glVertex3f(object.Tris[i].v2.x, object.Tris[i].v2.y, object.Tris[i].v2.z);
        glEnd();
    }
    glDisable(GL_TEXTURE_2D);
glutSwapBuffers();
}
```

So, there is something I'm doing wrong or forgetting to do?

Comment: Why are you setting the alpha to be the average of the red, green, and blue channels? Also, I think your `GL_TEXTURE_MAG_FILTER` should just be `GL_LINEAR`, not `GL_LINEAR_MIPMAP_LINEAR`. Finally, you're allocating 4 color channels, and filling them in, then telling OpenGL that there are only 3 channels in the call to `glTexImage2D()`. That seems wrong.

Comment: First problem that pops up, glTexImage2D(), your format should be GL_RGBA. The internal format too since you went through the trouble of creating a RGBA image.

Comment: Thanks, I changed the two GL_RGB in glTexImage2D to GL_RGBA and replace GL_LINEAR_MIPMAP_LINEAR with GL_LINEAR but the result is the same. The object is drawn all white, without the texture.

To be honest, I don't know why the alpha is the average of rgb channels. When I found this code, it was already that way. I tried to change it to 1.0f, but there was no difference.

Comment: I didn't know this function glGetError. Well, I tried to verify it after both glTexParameterf functions, gluBuild2DMipmaps and glTexImage2D and no errors returned. So, to solve this performance issue I have just to switch the order of gluBuild2DMipmaps and glTexImage2D?

Comment: No, to fix that particular problem you have to completely remove `glTexImage2D (...)`.